# Python record the time of typing

Tags: python

I need to record the time when the user send everyone of a series of phrases (strings) into a python script. How can I do that?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the module time:

```
import time
time.time()
```

Or (if you're looking for a human readable format) use datetime:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```

Call these methods when the string reaches the script (through the console's raw_input method, or through whatever other method that the script communicates).